# Shift array to right by adding a new element to left using js

Tags: javascript

I have a js 2d array

```
var a = [["a","b","c","d","e","f"]]
```

I need to discard the last and insert at the first position

```
var result = [["new","a","b","c","d","e"]]    //<------ "f" has to be discarded
```

I have tried with

```
a.unshift("new")
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Is your array really 2-dimensional?

Comment: Yes 2 dim array

Comment: @CodeGuy so can you have more than just one array inside the outer array then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `unshift` to add new values to the beginning of the array and `pop` to remove values from the end.

```js
let a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
a.unshift('new');
a.pop();
console.log(a);
```

Also, in your example - `a` is an array within array, so perform this on the inner array.

To be even more generic, you can extract this to function and perform this on every inner array with `map`:

```js
let a = [
  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
];
let result = a.map(innerArr => {
  innerArr.unshift('new');
  innerArr.pop();
  return innerArr;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I need a 2d array, this is not a 2d array

Comment: @CodeGuy a 1-D array nested in a 2-D array, is still 1-D. What you need is to realize that `unshift()` and `pop()` solves your problem.

Comment: @CodeGuy I added a clarification

Comment: I know that, But I am expecting the efficient and reliable technique

Comment: Or @CodeGuy a copy/paste solution? OmriAttiya answers your concerns here succinctly.

Comment: @CodeGuy I added a more generic way to do it for every item in an array

Answer (score 2):

You can first `splice` it and then use `unshift`

```js
var a = [
  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
]
a[0].splice(-1, 1);
a[0].unshift('new');
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = [["a","b","c","d","e","f"]]
a[0].unshift('new');
a[0].pop();
console.log(a);
```